# Unable to Modify Primary Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am working on a large existing website project. I have two tables: `Programs` and `ProgramCodes`.

`ProgramCodes` contains a foreign key to `Programs`. Because the program codes must be unique, the column `ProgramCodes.Value` has been set as the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProgramCodes](
    [Value] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ProgramsId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateAdded] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProgramCodes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Value] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProgramCodes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProgramCodes_Programs] FOREIGN KEY([ProgramsId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Programs] ([ProgramsId])
GO
```

This works okay. But when we mark a program as deleted, the program codes need to be available for use with other programs. To allow this, I planned to modify the program codes of "deleted" programs by appending "[DELETED]" to the code.

```
const string flag = "[DELETED]";

program.IsDeleted = true;
foreach (var programCode in program.ProgramCodes)
{
    if (!programCode.Value.EndsWith(flag))
        programCode.Value = programCode.Value + flag;
}
Repository.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

But this code produces the following error:

> The property 'Value' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Apparently, this error is related to the fact that I am trying to modify the primary key. But isn't there any way to do what I need here without going in and restructuring the entire database?

Comment: Bite the bullet and add a bit column to indicate this. There's no other decent way.

Comment: @spender: Actually, that won't solve the problem. Because the code must be unique, adding a column won't allow duplicates of keys used by deleted columns.

Comment: Unless you want to go dropping FKs, altering the FK data, alter the primary key data, then reapplying them... find another way... if you can't add a column can't you use another field to hold the flag instead? On that note why not just blank the date?

Comment: @PaulZahra: The issue is with the `Value` column. But that column is not part of any FK.

Comment: @JonathanWood Then, IMO, the code should not be constrained to be unique, so is unsuited to being a primary key. I would consider a new table of (unique) programs, that has a one to many relationship with your existing table. Your existing table would have an autoincrementing primary key and an additional field to indicate deletion. Painful, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do it without restructuring the database is to:

- Copy the rows that should be marked as deleted ;
- Delete the old ones;
- Add(restore) with new PK.

But it is possible if only the PK column is **never referenced as foreign key**. Otherwise it will require a lot of work to correctly duplicate or rereference all the data.

In such a case the addition of some flag field(restructuring of the database) is a more viable and dependable course of action.

**EDIT:**

About:

> copy the data into memory, delete them from the database

I am not sure that making such operations on the EF side is good idea. Why? Because it will possibly demand some additional transactional logic and will expose the peculiarities of the database.

I propose to make it a stored procedure that accepts original PK value as a parameter.

It just inserts the problematic row into the temporary table, deletes the original, changes the PK in the temporary table, and inserts the modified data back. My SQL is a bit rusty but such SP will be very simple (INSERT INTO new temporary table does not demand any DDL, so the query will be short and concise).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? The PK is not used as part of any foreign key. Do you mean to copy the data into memory, delete them from the database, and then add the modified data back to the database?